# will_paginate ajax pagination with thinking sphinx

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, thinking-sphinx, will-paginate

Has anyone ever tried paginating a thinking sphinx result set thru ajax?

I have this is in my controller action:

```
@results = Model.search params[:query], :page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 1
```

and in my application.js:

```
 $(".pagination a").live("click", function() {
   $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
   return false;
 });
```

Now, I have tried this and this works for normal active record pagination like so:

```
@results = Model.paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 1)
```

But if I use thinking-sphinx for getting the records the ajax pagination fails. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I got this already. But for the next one who might encounter this problem, all you have to do is to make sure that the links also pass the params for the query.

```
= will_paginate(@results, :params=>{"query"=> params[:query]})
```

Comment: There's no longer a need for this, will_paginate will paginate the ts results properly without that.